# Transform virtual screen in Wayland

Tags: wayland, virtual-screen

The top of my laptop screen is broken and I am unable to view anything within a 1600x82 rectangle.

Is it possible in Wayland/XWayland to transform the virtual screen so that only the visible area of my monitor is used?

I managed to hack together a solution in X using xrandr:

```
#!/bin/sh

xrandr --newmode "1600x818_60.00"  107.33  1600 1688 1856 2112  818 819 822 847  -HSync +Vsync
xrandr --addmode eDP1 1600x818_60.00
xrandr --output eDP1 --fb 1600x818 --panning 1600x818 --mode 1600x818_60.00

# Yes this is hacky, but it's necessary to work around xrandr weirdness
sleep 1
xrandr --fb 1600x818 --output eDP1 --mode 1600x900 --transform 1,0,0,0,1,-82,0,0,1
```

However, I want to be able to do this in Wayland as well.